# How to console.log a part of a list?

Tags: javascript

So basically I forgot how to call a part of list or `console.log` it.

I tried this  `console.log((1)yah)` and that didn't work.

```
var yah = ["hi","hello","goodbye"];

console.log(yah(1));
```

I just want it to `console.log ("hi")` y'know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. To point to a specific index in an Array, you would use [square brackets]. Also, arrays start at 0 in Javascript ;)

`console.log(yah[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You should use **square brackets**.

var yah = ["hi","hello","goodbye"];

Try this below

```
console.log(yah[0]);
```